# zabbix_sender syntax for discovery rules

Tags: zabbix

I have successfully installed a zabbix environment. Now I want to use zabbix_sender, to send data from a third party program to zabbix. I created a host “api_test”, and an item “test item ” with the key “java.test.item”. Sending

```
zabbix_sender -z localhost -p 10051 -s "api_test" -k java.test.item -o 1234
```

from the linux server works perfectly and adds a dataset as expected. 
The problem is, that I would like to use a discovery item, and I cannot find the right syntax for zabbix_sender. Here is how I configured the discovery rule:

[image: Discovery rule configuration]

And this is the Item Prototype:

[image: Item Prototype configuration]

I expected the following query to add an Item based on the item prototype, but nothing happens:

```
zabbix_sender -z localhost -p 10051 -s "api_test" -k java.th.discovery -o '{"data":[{"{#THNAME}:"test_thread"}]}'
```

I also tried with different quotations marks (single, double, without), but nothing seems to work.
Consequently, the following query I tried afterwards fails:

```
zabbix_sender -z localhost -p 10051 -s "api_test" -k java.th.ex["test_thread"] -o 98765
```

Question is: where am I mistaken? I guess it is the discovery rule, or the zabbix_sender syntax for discovery, but I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand why I could not send data before sending discovery results. Works in Zabbix 6.4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steffen, your configuration in Zabbix frontend is correct.

However, there is a mistake in JSON syntax that you use in the command line. Double quotes after {#THNAME} are missing:

```
{"data":[{"{#THNAME}:"test_thread"}]}
```

You should see the error message about it in discovery list:

[image]

It should work after that issue is fixed. If not, please provide details about your "@Thread for discovery" macro and the error message that you get.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem! i also did some mistake with the macros, but after some rading on zabbix macros I figured it out myself. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I just saw that you are a programmer at zabbix. Great service of you, to help out here at stack overflow! love your product and looking forward to continue using it at our company